# Automapper - reuse of mapping rules for projection

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, automapper, projection

Given 2 source entities:

```
class SourceA
{
   public string Info1 { get; set; }
   public string Info2 { get; set; }
}

class SourceB
{
   public A A { get; set; }

   public string OptionalExtraInfo { get; set; }
}
```

and one destination class:

```
class Dest
{
   public string ModifiedInfo1 { get; set; }
   public string ModifiedInfo2 { get; set; }

   public string ModifiedOptionalExtraInfo { get; set; }
}
```

I want to have the following code working with EF6:

```
var destsFromA = dbContext.SourcesA.ProjectTo<Dest>().ToArray();
var destsFromB = dbContext.SourcesB.ProjectTo<Dest>().ToArray();
```

So I define Automapper.net mappings:

- SourceA => Dest
- SourceB => Dest

with custom rules on how to project Info1 into ModifiedInfo1, and Info2=>ModifiedInfo2:

```
CreateMap<SourceA, Dest>()
    .ForMember(x => ModifiedInfo1, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Info1 + " something else-1")
    .ForMember(x => ModifiedInfo2, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Info1 + " something else-2")
    .ForMember(x => ModifiedOptionalExtraInfo, opt => opt.Ignore());

CreateMap<SourceB, Dest>()
    .ForMember(x => ModifiedInfo1, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.A.Info1 + " something else-1")
    .ForMember(x => ModifiedInfo2, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.A.Info2 + " something else-2")
    .ForMember(x => ModifiedOptionalExtraInfo, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.OptionalExtraInfo + " something else-3"));
```

How do I reuse mapping rules for ModifiedInfo1, ModifiedInfo2 in second mapping as they are the same as in the first case?

**UPDATE** In my certain case I figured out how to reuse *SourceA => Dest* mapping in a natural way.

First, I added a reverse-reference (navigation property) SourceA.B as these entities are really in one-to-zero-or-one relationship and EF has to know about that.

Then I **changed the aggregation root** in my application code and it became:

```
var destsFromA = dbContext.SourcesA.ProjectTo<Dest>().ToArray();
var destsFromB = dbContext.SourcesB.Select(x => x.A).ProjectTo<Dest>().ToArray();
```

so I only had to work with the only *SourceA => Dest* mapping

Finally I changed the mapping itself:

```
CreateMap<SourceA, Dest>()
    .ForMember(x => ModifiedInfo1, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Info1 + " something else-1")
    .ForMember(x => ModifiedInfo2, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Info1 + " something else-2")
    .ForMember(x => ModifiedOptionalExtraInfo, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.B ? src.B.OptionalExtraInfo + " something else-3" : null);
```

As this is a solution to a problem, but not an answer to the original question, I accepted **Ilya Chumakov**'s answer as a correct one.

Comment: How about having an intermediate class with propeties pointing to both source classes and then define the dest mapping over this intermediate class?

Comment: @DimiToulakis could you please provide a code snippet?

Comment: Will do it later on - not at my laptop at the moment

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Parametrize mappings with expressions:

```
opt.MapFrom(expression)

.ForMember(x => x.Foo, expression)
```

It's easy to extract these expression variables with ReSharper, so it could look like:

```
Expression<Func<SourceA, string>> expression = src => src.Info1 + " something else-1";
var func = expression.Compile();

cfg.CreateMap<SourceA, Dest>()
    .ForMember(x => x.ModifiedInfo1, 
        opt => opt.MapFrom(expression));

cfg.CreateMap<SourceB, Dest>()
    .ForMember(x => x.ModifiedInfo1,
        opt => opt.MapFrom(src => func(src.A)));
```

**Update:** In case of LINQ to SQL translation, the solution becomes much more complicated. `expression.Compile()` won't work and a new expression should be created:

```
Expression<Func<SourceA, string>> expression = src => src.Info1 + "foo";

//it should contain `src => src.A.Info1 + "foo"`
var newExpression = ConvertExpression(expression);
```

Basic implementation with `ExpressionVisitor`:

```
private static Expression<Func<SourceB, string>> 
    ConvertExpression(Expression<Func<SourceA, string>> expression)
{
    var newParam = Expression.Parameter(typeof(SourceB), "src");

    var newExpression = Expression.Lambda<Func<SourceB, string>>(
        new ReplaceVisitor().Modify(expression.Body, newParam), newParam);

    return newExpression;
}    

class ReplaceVisitor : ExpressionVisitor
{
    private ParameterExpression parameter;

    public Expression Modify(Expression expression, ParameterExpression parameter)
    {
        this.parameter = parameter;

        return Visit(expression);
    }

    protected override Expression VisitLambda<T>(Expression<T> node)
    {
        return Expression.Lambda<Func<SourceB, bool>>(
            Visit(node.Body), 
            Expression.Parameter(typeof(SourceB)));
    }

    protected override Expression VisitParameter(ParameterExpression node)
    {
        if (node.Type == typeof(SourceA))
        {
            return Expression.Property(parameter, nameof(SourceB.A));
        }

        throw new InvalidOperationException();
    }
}
```

Comment: I haven't tried yet, but are sure that func() invocation will be properly translated into SQL? As there should be a way for this mapping to be used via .ProjectTo() queryable extension

Comment: @AndreyPesoshin of course `func()` won't be translated to SQL. Stupid me.      We need to create new expression from original one. I've added a proof-of-concept code to answer (tested).

Comment: yes, It looks like that rebuilding the expression is the only way to reuse it in several mappings. I solved my problem in another way (edited a question), but this method is acceptable for original question.

Also just got an idea - I could transform the expression itself by automapper as it provides such ability https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Expression-Translation-(UseAsDataSource)#useasdatasource

It would be a little-bit hacky as then I should create a mapping beetween A and B which are not really to-be-mapped, but will eliminate the need in expression tree parsing

Comment: @AndreyPesoshin, thanks! I didn't take seriously this Automapper feature before.

Answer (score 0):

A quick and easy solution would be to use an intermediate class.

First the classes who are used then later on in the posting

```
public class SourceA 
{
    public string A { get; set; }
}

public class SourceB
{
    public string B { get; set; }
}

public class Dest
{
    public string ValueFromSourceA { get; set; }

    public string ValueFromSourceB { get; set; }
}
```

That said here is the intermediate class:

```
public class Intermediate
{
    public SourceA SourceA { get; set; } = new SourceA();

    public SourceB SourceB { get; set; } = new SourceB();
}
```

Now let's start sticking the parts together with Automapper.

Defining profile classes

```
public class DestinationProfile : Profile
{
    public DestinationProfile()
    {
        this.CreateMap<Intermediate, Dest>()
            .ForMember(destination => destination.ValueFromSourceA, 
                       opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.SourceA.A))
            .ForMember(destination => destination.ValueFromSourceB, 
                       opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.SourceB.B));
    }
}

public class IntermediateProfile : Profile
{
    public IntermediateProfile()
    {
        this.CreateMap<Intermediate, Dest>()
            .ForMember(destination => destination.ValueFromSourceA, map => map.MapFrom(src => src.SourceA.A))
            .ForMember(destination => destination.ValueFromSourceB, map => map.MapFrom(src => src.SourceB.B));

    // ----- TODO: Create mapping for source classes.
    }
}
```

And here comes the heavy lifting for the mapping we marked as todo above. 
You can use IValueResolver interface from Automapper to define value mapping.
So in our case the resolvers look like

```
public class SourceAResolver : IValueResolver<SourceA, Intermediate, SourceA>
{
    public SourceA Resolve(SourceA source, Intermediate destination, SourceA destMember, ResolutionContext context)
    {
        return source;
    }
}

public class SourceBResolver : IValueResolver<SourceB, Intermediate, SourceB>
{
    public SourceB Resolve(SourceB source, Intermediate destination, SourceB destMember, ResolutionContext context)
    {
        return source;
    }
}
```

With the above now we are able to replace the todo statement

```
        this.CreateMap<SourceA, Intermediate>()
            .ForMember(destination => destination.SourceA, map => map.ResolveUsing<SourceAResolver>());
        this.CreateMap<SourceB, Intermediate>()
            .ForMember(destination => destination.SourceB, map => map.ResolveUsing<SourceBResolver>());
```

Finally we register our profile classes to the Automapper

```
public static class AutomapperProfile
{
    public static void Configure()
    {
        Mapper.Initialize(cfg =>
        {
            cfg.AddProfile<DestinationProfile>();
            cfg.AddProfile<IntermediateProfile>();
        }); 
    }
}
```

Firing up a console with the below code snippet helps testing our stuff

```
        AutomapperProfile.Configure();
        var a = new SourceA {A = "Value A"};

        var b = new SourceB() {B = "Value B"};

        var intermediate = new Intermediate() {SourceA = a, SourceB = b};

        var destination = AutoMapper.Mapper.Map<Dest>(intermediate);

        Console.WriteLine(destination.ValueFromSourceA);

        Console.Read();
```

Done!

*Note:* The code snippets provided are just coded to demo the usage/meaning of what is meant by "intermediate" class - have not implemented the way back to the source classes.

Have fun with it :)

Comment: as you can see in the question above, it won't be acceptable as instead of Mapper.Map<> the mapping should be performed via IQueryable<> projection

Comment: @andrey Not needed to overcomplicate things :) The provided sample works also with IQueryable<> using the IQueryable<> itself. That said assuming `var mappedItems = new List<Dest>(); var items = new List<Intermediate>(); // ---- create some entries in the items collection 
items.Where(x => x.SourceA.A.Contains("1")).ToList().ForEach(x => mappedItems.Add(Mapper.Map<Dest>(x)));` All works like a charm :)

Comment: it's not really about overcomplication.

When you use Mapper.Map (as in both of your examples) - the mapping itself is performed using CPU with objects stored in RAM

To be exact, in the second example you make a transition from IQueryable<T> to IEnumerable<T> with a.ToList() called and then perform a standard RAM-based mapping.

The question's topic is on how to make in work with mapping being performed in the SQL by .ProjectTo<>() automapper queryable extension method https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Queryable-Extensions

So custom value resolvers simply won't work here